I need help resolving egregious typos in this complex analysis theorem statement

First of all, I tried to go online to find a similar theorem statement but couldn't find anything.
I underlined the points that I'm confused about.

The wording in the first underlined part is weird. Does it mean gamma 1 and gamma 2 are built by gluing straight segments and circular arcs together? Also, what does "and f: gamma1 -> gamma2" mean? f was initially defined as a conformal map from D1 to D2 already. I thought the goal of the theorem was to extend f onto its boundary gamma 1?


I don't understand their definition of M_gamma. What's the domain and range of M and how do you find M_gamma given the "gamma" parameter?

Also, if the goal of the theorem is to extend f onto its boundary, how can the construction of the extension involve f (in the composition)? Isn't that circular logic?


If anyone could help me find a similar theorem that's written more legibly or help me resolve my confusions about the wording in this one, I'd be very grateful. I honestly cannot make heads or tails what is being stated here.
This theorem was stated in the section immediately before Schwarz Christoffel transformations

I believe that the gist is this, for the line-segment case.:
For i = 1, 2, you have a region $D_i$, with $\partial D_i = \Gamma_i$, and a subset $\gamma_i \subset \Gamma_i$, and $\gamma_i$ is a line segment (or, in a separate theorem, a circle arc).
You have a function $f : D_1 \to D_2$, and $f(\gamma_1) = \gamma_2$ (and presumably for $x \in \Gamma_1\setminus \gamma_1$, you have f(x) \notin \gamma_2).
Then the claim is that there's a new function $g$ (or $f$-with-a-tilde) that agrees with $f$ on ...something. I apologize for being unable to make sense of the actual claim. "$f$ could be extended throughout $\gamma_1$" doesn't make sense. I suspect that maybe it's saying "could be extended throughout the complement of $D_1$", because for something in (some parts of) the complement, you can mirror it across $\gamma_1$ to get something in $D_1$, to which you can then apply $f$, and then you can flip the result (an element of $D_2$) across $\gamma_2$ to get something in the complement of $D_2$. But...jeez. Can you get a different source?

This is from the textbook that my prof reads off of which he wrote. I usually try to find a different source but I can't find one for this theorem.

Sigh. It feels as if you might want a different prof. :(
